# Trigger Event using key press?

Tags: python, opencv, triggers

I am trying to make my program take 8 pictures only when a key is pressed but I cant find a solution for it. I tried the keyboard package and whenever I would do key is pressed it would throw error. 
By the way here is my code-

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('morning.mp4')

img_counter = 0
start_time = time.time()
x=0


while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(47) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    #here is where the image capturing comes into play    
    if time.time() - start_time > 14: #<---- Check if 15 sec passed
        img_name = "frame_{}.png".format(x)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_counter))
        start_time = time.time()
        x += 1
    img_counter += 1
    if x == 8:
        break  

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After the comment "#here is where the image capturing comes into play" until the break statement is where   I take pictures of the video and I want to trigger that part of code with a keypress. Any idea how I should go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you break while loop after keypress. You should use some boolean variable to point when script should capture images.

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('morning.mp4')

img_counter = 0
start_time = time.time()
x=0
capture_images = False

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(47) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        capture_images = True
    if capture_images:
        #here is where the image capturing comes into play    
        if time.time() - start_time > 14: #<---- Check if 15 sec passed
            img_name = "frame_{}.png".format(x)
            cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
            print("{} written!".format(img_counter))
            start_time = time.time()
            x += 1
        img_counter += 1
        if x == 8:
            break  

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```